# Apache Spark: Can't use Matplotlib on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, matplotlib, pyspark

I wanted to do a simple thing.

On my spark cluster I converted my Spark dataframe to pandas datframe for plotting.

```
+--------------------+-----+
|              window|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|[2018-04-10 15:00...|  770|
|[2018-04-10 00:42...|  100|
|[2018-04-10 04:14...|   54|
|[2018-04-06 15:54...|   36|
|[2018-04-10 04:46...|  304|
|[2018-04-10 20:36...|  347|
|[2018-04-10 03:26...|   41|
|[2018-04-10 21:10...|   85|
|[2018-04-10 11:44...|  426|
|[2018-04-10 12:32...|  754|
|[2018-04-10 00:28...|   61|
|[2018-04-10 05:36...|  478|
|[2018-04-06 07:04...|   18|
|[2018-04-10 22:14...|  195|
|[2018-04-10 23:40...|  175|
|[2018-04-10 00:20...|  229|
|[2018-04-10 03:10...|  209|
|[2018-04-10 01:28...|   67|
|[2018-04-09 18:52...|    9|
|[2018-04-10 19:06...| 3548|
+--------------------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

But now that I try to plot it,

```
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
​
pdf.plot()  # pdf is the pandas datframe
```

I get the errors:

```
unknown magic command 'matplotlib'
UnknownMagic: unknown magic command 'matplotlib'
```

I can't understand why the error is coming. I already created the dataframe, I just showed it and it showed fine. Now, I am just trying to plot it, with matplotlib installed.

How to plot on Jupyter notebook that runs on PySpark kernel on a cluster?

Comment: the problem is not with the import , try removing `%matplotlib inline` and run the code

Comment: @Kalyan is right, try to show the full error message that includes the line that is throwing the issue. It helps debugging :)

Comment: Did you use Sparkmagic and Livy to connect to your cluster?

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing

```
%matplotlib inline
```

add the following code

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

Comment: tried that it gives me the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_line_magic'
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_line_magic'

Comment: are you using IBM's jupyter notebook?

Comment: yes, I tried running with it..I got the error..without it..still get an error..a different one,,RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable from IPython.display import display is also not solving

Comment: looks like, you need to install ipython in the azure notebook, so, run the following command, $ pip install ipython

Comment: could you give me the complete error you got when you removed %matplotlib inline and ran the code

Comment: @InAFlash I know this is a bit old but I'm having the same issue. I am however using IBM's jupyter notebook. I'm remotely connecting to a data lake and having the issue described above. Any ideas on this?